# Borrar una imagen adjunta en C#

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, visual-studio

Estoy programando con C# en Visual Studio. Tengo el siguiente código para adjuntar una imagen:

```
     if (fuFotoUsuario.HasFile)
    {
        extension = FuncionesApoyo.Extension(fuFotoUsuario.FileName);
        if (File.Exists(directorio + "\\fotousuario." + extension))
            File.Delete(directorio + "\\fotousuario." + extension);
        fuFotoUsuario.SaveAs(directorio + "\\fotousuario." + extension);
        editado.Foto = FuncionesApoyo.UrlFichero(Session, ruta + "fotousuario." + extension + "?mtm=" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmssfff"));
```

Eso funciona bien. Ahora he hecho un botón para eliminar la imagen que esta subida, pero no me funciona. Tengo lo siguiente:

```
  string directorio = 
  ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DirectorioImagenes"].Replace("imagenes", 
 "clubs");
     string ruta = 
   ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RutaImagenes"].Replace("imagenes", 
   "clubs");

    if (!Directory.Exists(directorio))
        return;

    string extension;
    if (editado.Foto.Length > 0)
    {
        extension = FuncionesApoyo.Extension(editado.Foto);
        if (File.Exists(directorio + "\\fotousuario." + extension))
            File.Delete(directorio + "\\fotousuario." + extension);
        editado.Foto = "";
    }
```

A que se puede deber?

Muchas gracias de antemano!!

Comment: Te lanza alguna excepción?

Comment: Nada. Simplemente recarga la página de nuevo.

Comment: Entonces,es una aplicación asp entiendo. Por otro lado..por que haces el replace de imagenes a clubs antes de eliminarlo?

Comment: Sí. Es una aplicación asp. Es simplemente para cambiarlo de directorio. En otra parte de la aplicación si se borra la foto, pero aquí no logro hacerlo funcionar.

Comment: Te lo pregunto porque es posible que el directorio tras hacer el replace no sea correcto y no exista, con lo cual entraría en `if (!Directory.Exists(directorio))
        return;`.Yo pondría un punto de depuración ahi y comprobaría que tiene `directorio` por si fuera incorrecto.

Comment: Te refieres a hacer esto no?  if (!directorio.EndsWith("\\"))
            directorio += "\\" + editado.Foto;
        else
            directorio += editado.Foto;
        if (!Directory.Exists(directorio))
            Directory.CreateDirectory(directorio);

Comment: En realidad mi consejo era que pusieras un punto de depuración en ese método para que pudieras analizar exactamente lo que está pasando :)

Comment: de donde sale `editado.Foto` ? porque puede que no tenga ningun elemento. O mejor dicho, estos dos parte de codigo que muestras en que contexto se encuentan? porque si son dos acciones diferentes recuerda que en un entoeno web no hay estado, o sea no conservas la informacion

Comment: editado.foto es la imagen que adjuntas, que luego se guarda.

Comment: ok pero cuando realizas la operacion de borrar como recuperas esa entidad ?

Comment: A que entidad te refieres? Lo que hago es poner la ruta de la imagen en blanco.

Comment: La variable `editado` esta entiendo es una variable de una clase que defines, eso es una entidad. Entiendo que a pones en blanco, peor antes evaluas en un if evaluando `editado.Foto.Length` pero no pusiste el codigo de como recuperas esa informacion

Comment: Sí, tienes razón. No estaba cogiendo de una forma correcta la variable editando.foto. Lo que hize fue directamente acceder al ID de la imagen subida. Ya está solucionado. Muchas gracias